# Error trying to use BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

For a school assignment we need to use some moviedata. Instead of copy/pasting all the info I need I thought I would scrape it off IMDB. However I am not familiar with Python and I am running into an issue here.

This is my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://www.imdb.com"
values = {'q' : 'The Matrix'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values).encode("utf-8")
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
r = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
```

That code keeps giving me the error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in
> <module>
>     soup = BeautifulSoup(r)   File "C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py",
> line 153, in __init__
>     builder = builder_class()   File "C:\Users\My Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py",
> line 39, in __init__
>     return super(HTMLParserTreeBuilder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict
```

'

Does any of you great minds know what I am doing wrong?

I tried using google and found a post mentioning it migt had something to do with requests so I unistalled requests and installed it again... didn't work.

Comment: next time use button `{}` to format error.

Comment: I run it on Python 3.6, Linux Mint 18.2 and it works. It only informs that I should use `lxml` or `html.parser` in `BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')` but it doesn't give  your error message.

Comment: BTW: see [OMDB API](http://www.omdbapi.com/). You can get data as JSON and you can convert it into python dictionary using module `json`

Comment: I can get this error only if I would use `BeautifulSoup(r, strict="")` but you doesn't use `strict` in `BeautifulSoup`. Problem is `BeautifulSoup`, not `requests` which you even not use in code. `urllib.request` is standard module in Python and has nothing to do with module `requests`. How did you install `BeautifulSoup` ? Using `pip install bs4` ?

Comment: check `BeautifulSoup` what version you use `import bs4 ; python(bs4.__version__)` (I have 4.6.0) or try to reinstall `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Html parser built-in class started to have `strict `argument since Python 3.2. It looks like your Python version used here is less than 3.2. Well, you can always workaround it by switching to `html5lib` or `lxml` parsers, but that does not solve the problem, of course.